# Расширяющаяся кнопка

Tags: html, css

Как можно сделать подобную кнопку, но без привязки к каким-то "с потолка взятым значениям"? margin-left в данном примере я брал на глаз. Но если изменится текст, то все полетит. Возможно у кого-то есть реализация подобного в лучшем виде. Если поделитесь - буду очень благодарен.

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.btn {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.btn::after {
    padding-left: 10px;
    content: attr(aria-label);
    margin-left: -180px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.btn:hover::after {
    margin-left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" class="btn" aria-label="Change theme">[T]</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Мало информации, исходя из вопроса можно сделать через min-width и min-height

Comment: Вообще, если вам нужно *вручную* прописывать значения для каждого отдельного элемента с немного отличающимися пропорциями, значит вы плохо написали стили, перепишите их, попробуйте другой подход.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Вижу цель, не вижу препятствий..." Можно менять текст и шрифт:

```css
/* For example only --> */ body{display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:center;align-items:center;gap:4px;background-color:grey}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  height: 2em;
  max-width: min-content;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 0.33em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 15px/1em serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.btn::before,
.btn::after {
  content: attr(aria-label);
  display: inline-block;
}
.btn::before {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in;
}
.btn:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
.btn::after {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 .5em;
  font-size: 0;
  color: transparent;
  transition: font-size .5s ease;
}
.btn:hover::after {
  font-size: inherit;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn" style="font-size: 36px;" aria-label="Change theme">[T]</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" aria-label="Change language">[L]</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" aria-label="This text is very very very long">[LITERA]</a>
<a href="#" class="btn" aria-label="Ooops!!">[MAIN TITLE]</a>
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, не подумал про изменение размера шрифта.